# Is it possible to make a game object immune to having a joint attached to it?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I have some objects in a game that are supposed to be interacted with by having a fixed joint created on collision, but I also have objects that are made to be obstacles and of course I don't want to interact with those obstacles. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: What makes an object an obstacle? For example, is it tagged a certain way? Is there a monobehavior whose attachment makes an object an obstacle or not an obstacle? Question is unclear about the objective. What have you already tried? Please share your research. Consider taking the [tour] and reading [ask].

Comment: Different tags, different layers so collision is treated differently in the first place, certain components to check for on collision ... ?

Comment: sorry for being unclear, they aren't tagged or anything but the objects that i can interact with are all spheres were as the obstacles are cubes.

Comment: One possible solution is to tag all of your obstacles with a tag then use `if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("ObstacleTagNameHere")) {return;}` at the start of the `OnCollisionEnter` method which starts the joint creation logic.